# Can I debug iOS device with remote OS X desktop through VPN?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, vpn, remote-desktop

The situation I'm having now is like:

1. A OS X desktop is in my home.
2. I'll bring a Windows laptop and an iPhone with me outside all the time.

I want  to develop iOS applications with my Windows laptop, connecting the desktop's Xcode through RDP, and I want to use my phone as a remote-debug device. I already know the fact that I cannot attach a device to Xcode if the OS X computer and iOS device are not on the same network. So I'm thinking of using VPN to place the desktop and phone on the same virtual network.

My question is:
Would Xcode let me to attach an iOS device on the same VPN?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) The Mac and iOS device have to be on the same Wi-Fi network for the remote debugging to work.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes, I know that. But doesn't that solved with VPN?